# Is it known that certain extensions of the integers are UFDs?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For an integer $n$, let $\omega=\sqrt n$ unless $n=\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and in that case let $\omega = (1+\sqrt n)/2$.  Then the ring $Z[\omega]$ is well known to be integrally closed.  For $p$ a prime, let $Q_p$ denote the subring of the rationals consisting of those whose denominators are not divisible by $p$.  I and my collaborators have shown that for all prime $p$ and all integers $n$, the ring $Q_p(\omega)$ is a UFD.  It occurs to me that this might well known to number theorists.  The proof involves something like 8 cases.  The final conclusion is that $Z(\omega)$ is an inverse limit of UFDs, even though it is frequently not a UFD itself.

Comment: Your ring is a Dedekind domain with finitely many prime ideals and any such thing is a PID.

Comment: If $n=-4$, your ring, ${\bf Z}[2i]$, is not integrally closed, is it?

Comment: Yes, we need $n$ squarefree.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that $n$ was square free.

Comment: So, maybe you could edit "square-free" into the question? People shouldn't have to trawl through the comments to find it.

Answer (score 7):

In fact the following is true.

**Proposition:** Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of a number field $K$. For any $p_0$, it is possible to find finitely many primes $p_1, ..., p_n \ge p_0$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K[p_1^{-1}, ..., p_n^{-1}]$ is a PID.

*Proof.* Find ideals $I_1, ..., I_m$ representing every ideal class in the ideal class group of $\mathcal{O}_K$ whose norms are not divisible by primes less than $p_0$ and invert all primes dividing their norms. $\Box$

---

**Edit (12/4/13):** Regarding the last line, every Dedekind domain is an inverse limit of UFDs. Indeed, every Dedekind domain is the inverse limit of its localizations at every maximal ideal, and these are all DVRs (in particular PIDs, in particular UFDs).

Comment: I think this answers my question.  I guess that we can now invert all the rest of the primes but one.  So we can take $p_0$ to be the prime we don't want to invert.  I assume that if we take a UFD and invert all but one of the remaining primes, we still get a UFD.

Comment: In the last statement either "maximal" should be replaced with "prime" or we should add the fraction field to the inverse limit.